# WPF: how to alignment 2 labels in different sizes

Tags: wpf, alignment, label

I have simple `Grid` with 2 label, one of them get its value (0-100) from `Slider Value` and i want this 2 `labels` show me the `Slider Value` in this format:

x Value - the value need to be in different size and much bigger then the 'x' char, So this is my start position:

[image]

And while the `Value` changed things become ugly:

[image]

My code:

```
<Grid Margin="857,112,87,383" >
    <Label Content="{Binding ElementName=knobSlider, Path=Value, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
           Foreground="#FFB2B2B2" VerticalAlignment="Center"  HorizontalAlignment="Center"
       FontFamily="Buxton Sketch"  FontSize="40" Grid.Column="1" Padding="0,0,0,0"/>
    <Label Content="x" FontSize="20" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Grid.Column="1" Foreground="#FFB2B2B2" Padding="0,20,0,0"/>
</Grid>
```

Any idea how to fix it ?

BTW: i want my value will show with only 1 decimal number after the point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add a string format to the Label that should give you all the control over the number you need.

For example:

```
<Label Content="{Binding ElementName=knobSlider, Path=Value, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" ContentStringFormat="N1" />
```

An alternative is to add the string format directly to the binding. That works too. Just like that:

```
<Label Content="{Binding ElementName=knobSlider, Path=Value, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, StringFormat=N2}" />
```

For your second problem the design of your grid is the problem. Grid allows you to create columns and rows. Make use of it! Like so:

```
    <Grid>
      <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
      </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
      <Label Grid.Column="0" Content="x" Padding="0,20,0,0" />
      <Label Grid.Column="1" Content="{Binding ElementName=knobSlider, Path=Value, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
    </Grid>
```

Now both labels are in their own column and can't overlap.

Comment: The first option works fine, the second (inside the binding) show all numbers after the point, BTW what about my first question ?

Comment: I did read your question multiple times and I actually don't understand your first question. Please write that more clearly.

Comment: See my first pic and see what happening after the value changed (second pic), the char 'x' is hidden by the value